# \oddfoot error message

Tags: errors, undefined

I began to receive the following error message, which I do not recognise or understand, nor can I intuit how to begin debugging it, so I'm asking for pointers.

```
./MPD-M5-immersion.tex:102: Undefined control sequence.
\mpdofootl ->\itshape {\oddfoot 
                                }
l.102 \end{quote}
```

The error currently occurs four times if I suppress errors, when the PDF output completes, with no visible output errors. When I visit the error-associated lines e.g. here line 102, in the TeX file, there is nothing visible to suggest what is causing the error.

```
100    \begin{quote}
101    \textbf{\emph{Immersion in water is the foundational sign of participation in the new covenant}}.
102    \end{quote}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can begin debugging this error?

Comment: \oddfoot suggest that you are at a page break and something is wrong with the page style definition. To debug it try to make a  complete minimal example. Force pages with \newpage.

Comment: there is no `\oddfoot` command in standard latex, there is an `\@oddfoot` command, so this looks like a typo in the definition of `\mpdofootl`

Comment: Resolved. I had defined `\oddfoot`. I defined instead `\oddfooter`.